# How to make pull right display properly?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug

This is my current code

```
 .tag-container.bottom-border.col-middle
    h1.text-center {{ tag.name }}
    button.btn.btn-follow.pull-right(ng-hide="hasFollowed" ng-click="tagArticles.followTag()") Follow
```

I want to make the tag.name in the middle, and the button in the right, but it didn't display correctly. How should I structure these two part? What css should I use?

Thanks.

**Update**

This is the simplified code about basic html

```
<row>
  <div>
    <h1> Tag name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="pull-right">
    <button>Follow</button>
  </div>
 </row>
```

Feel free to work on it. Thanks

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @ChrisBier it's jade with angularJS. Feel free to give me simple html example.

Comment: Please provide an HTML / CSS code sample and/or demo.

Comment: @Michael_B I have add a HTML code sample. thanks.

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, I still want a easy way to do this. I have a lot of work need to make stuff in one line. For example, how to put the `<p>Tag:</p>` and `<a href='#'>Tag</a>` in one line. I think it must be simple, but I cannot figure out. Can you give me a general solution? I am really new for front-end

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for your help. Because I need a simple answer, I think Michael Stanaland's answer is more simple and understandable, Although it use a fixed number to control the position. I like this answer, but I still need a more simple one.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you need a pure bootstrap answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to pure bootstrap styles, something like this would work:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h1 class="text-center">Tag name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-follow " style="margin-top: 1.5em;">Follow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll need some extra styling to vertically center the button (to replace the inline style adding 1.5em margin to the top).

Also that styling centers the button below the h1 in mobile breakpoints ... that may or may not be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer is totally solve my problem. But if the solution without fixed value, it would be better.